# Laravel 5 redirect with error not working in Handler.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to redirect to a page which displays the error message from `Handler.php`. My implementation will redirect successfully, but will not show the message on the page.

**Redirect Function** *(Handler.php)*

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException)
        return \Redirect::to('administrator/media')->with('errorMessage', 'File size is too big.');

    // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

**View** *(media.blade.php)*

```html
@if (Session::get('errorMessage')) 
<div class="m-t-20">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Error!!</h4>                            
            <p>{{ Session::get('errorMessage') }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Show us the view please.

Comment: @ChinLeung question updated.

Comment: @ChinLeung Sorry for the wrong code snippet. Please check the updated code now.

Comment: Are you sure it's getting there? If you put a `dd` before the redirect, does it stop there?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes stopped when dd() before the redirection code

Comment: Alright, what about the controller that handles the route? Also, if you `dd(Session::all())`, do you see your data?

Comment: @ChinLeung No. Nothing shown about session. Also, this is handler.php, not controller.

Comment: I mean the controller that handles the route of `administration/media`.

Comment: @ChinLeung No, session prints but no trace for the error message.

Comment: Is Handler.php a middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It looks like you are redirecting in a middleware. Anyways, this should work:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException)
{
    $request->session()->flash('errorMessage', 'File size is too big.');
    return \Redirect::to('administrator/media');
}

// Code omitted for brevity
```

}

Comment: Using `->with()` on a `redirect()` calls `$this->session->flash($k, $v);`; so there's really no difference between your code and what was posted.

Comment: In a middleware, strangely enough, it does. Because I have encountered a very similar issue recently. Using facades during the App boot sequence, as in middlewares, gives erroneous results.

Comment: I've never had to use `$request->session()->flash(...)` in a middleware; `back()->with(...)` and `redirect()->with()` have worked fine. I have had to use `->reflash()` when middlewares overlapped, so maybe something similar is happening here. Btw, `Handler.php` is not a middleware, it's in `app/Exceptions`.

Comment: Let's wait what the person who posed the question says. If it doesn't work I'll delete my answer. I answer in good faith because it resembles a past issue in my project. So it's not a middleware but still a laravel core file. Not a custom controller.

Comment: No problem. Also, I'm not saying to delete it btw; just pointing out that from my view, and looking into the code, I don't see how this answers the question (since the code is doing the same thing in both cases). Could be wrong though.

Comment: :) The Laravel Bootstrap is a mystery to me. To many. Once had to reinstall Laravel and reapply the MVC's to make a glitch go away. Also with a redirect (after successful login). Never found out the root cause.